# NIntegrate Error-Estimate Question

Tags: numerical-integration

When I do some complicated 4-dimensional integral numerically, *Mathematica* tells me its estimate for the value of the integral, and its estimate for the value of the error in the calculation.

The integrand:

```
Integrand[x_, y_, z_, Ekb_] := Sqrt[-4.14195`*^-29 +1.38065`*^-29 Ekb + (1.7055100000000003`*^-29 2.71828`^(-((2.76817`*^8 ((0.986286` x + 0.165048` y)^2 + z^2))/(1.` + 4707.27` (-0.165048` x + 0.986286` y)^2))))/(1.` + 4707.27` (-0.165048` x +0.986286` y)^2) + (2.4364400000000005`*^-29 2.71828`^(-((2.76817`*^8 ((0.986286` x -0.165048` y)^2 + z^2))/(1.` + 4707.27` (0.165048` x + 0.986286` y)^2))))/(1.` + 4707.27`(0.165048` x + 0.986286` y)^2)]/(1.` + 2.71828`^(7.2429699999999995`*^28 (-2.7613`*^-29 + 1.38065`*^-29 Ekb)))
```

The Integration:

```
Re@NIntegrate[Integrand[x,y,z,Ekb],{x,-9.53853 10^(-5),9.53853 10^(-5)},{y,-57 10^(-5),57 10^(-5)},{z,-4.37824 10^(-5),4.37824 10^(-5)},{Ekb,0,7*3/17},Method ->     {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "MultiDimensionalRule", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100}]
```

It puts out the error message:

> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 100 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 1.51764*10^-27+7.31069*10^-26 I and 1.0039003041591675`*^-28 for the integral and error estimates. >>

Should this be interpreted as (1.51764*10^-27+7.31069*10^-26 I) ± 1.0039003041591675`*^-28,
or
(1.51764*10^-27+7.31069*10^-26 I) ± 5.0195*10^-29
  ?

Comment: I have never seen Mathematica output like that. Are you sure you are actually using that? If so, please provide the code you are using.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to error messages/warnings like this: `NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 33 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 1.9558072180392028 and 0.06781302015519788 for the integral and error estimates.`?

Comment: Yes indeed! I'm sorry for being unclear. was Just trying to get that message in the typing box :)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries   
So in your example, should i interpret the answer as:
1.95581 (\[PlusMinus]0.067813)
or
1.95581 (\[PlusMinus]0.0339065)

Thanks again!

Comment: I wouldn't use the results from an error message. First try some of the options of `NIntegrate` to see whether that helps. `MaxPoints` and `Maxrecursion` could be good ones, and several of the `Method`s available to `NIntegrate` could be better suited for the function that you have .

Comment: Thanks for the tips :)
I did play around with those.
I found MaxErrorIncreases to have the best effect on the accuracy.
My integrand looks pretty ugly though, and i think it wont be easy to get a very good precision for reasonable computation times. I guess i accepted the fact i have to deal with some inaccuracy, but for now I'm just trying to find out how high that inaccuracy actually is

Comment: The integration is over 4 variables (x,y,z,Ekb). I only need the real part of the answer. The integrand is: Sqrt[-4.14195*10^-29 + 1.38065*10^-29 Ekb + (
 1.70551*10^-29 2.71828^(-((
   2.76817*10^8 ((0.986286 x + 0.165048 y)^2 + z^2))/(
   1. + 4707.27 (-0.165048 x + 0.986286 y)^2))))/(
 1. + 4707.27 (-0.165048 x + 0.986286 y)^2) + (
 2.43644*10^-29 2.71828^(-((
   2.76817*10^8 ((0.986286 x - 0.165048 y)^2 + z^2))/(
   1. + 4707.27 (0.165048 x + 0.986286 y)^2))))/(
 1. + 4707.27 (0.165048 x + 0.986286 y)^2)]/(1. + 2.71828^(
 7.24297*10^28 (-2.7613*10^-29 + 1.38065*10^-29 Ekb)))

Comment: Boundary values?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries 

{x,-9.53853 10^(-5),9.53853 10^(-5)},{y,-57 10^(-5),57 10^(-5)},{z,-4.37824 10^(-5),4.37824 10^(-5)},{Ekb,0,7*3/17}

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries     Or even better:     {Ekb,0,7*3/17}         and x,y,z over all values where the integrand is real

Comment: I have been using the GlobalAdaptive strategy and the MultidimensionalRule, since they seemed to produce the quickest and most accurate results

Comment: Without any code in the question I do not think this is reproducible or useful for future visitors (too localized).

Comment: @YvesKlett
  
  Ok i get that :)  I edited the original post by adding the integrand and the integration procedure. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

In the case of a complex-valued integrand, how to interpret "NIntegrate obtained a and b for the integral and error estimates":

The rough interpretation is: the disk in the complex plane centered on a with radius b, or alternatively (what is larger), the range (a - b - b*I) to (a + b + b*I).

Longer answer: b is the sum of "error estimates" on individual subintervals in the integration range you specified. Each "error estimate" is the absolute difference between an integral estimate using ~2*n sampling points and an integral estimate using ~n sampling points. Important: This absolute difference, called the "error estimate", can only be reliably interpreted as a bound on the error of the integration rule *if* the integration is actually converging. The message "The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 100 times" indicates this may not be the case for your integral.